# Query with join, like and or. not find the row correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a code:

```
SELECT 
produto_nota.id, 
produto.descricao, 
produto_nota.lote 
FROM produto_unidade 
join produto_nota on produto_nota.id = produto_unidade.produto_nota_id 
join produto_licitacao on produto_licitacao.id = produto_nota.produto_licitacao_id 
join produto on produto.id = produto_licitacao.produto_id 
where produto_nota.lote like '%1b%' or produto.descricao like '%1b%' limit 20
```

I like to get a row:

```
produto_nota.id = 1
produco.descricao = TEST
produto_nota.lote = 1B60
```

Why the code not find the row? If I search by `TEST`, it's works

The trouble is on `produto_nota.lote`, the `produto.descricao` works correctly.

Comment: Because the row is being filtered out either by the `join` conditions or the `where` conditions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you help me to fix it?

Comment: When you try only `produto_nota.lote like...` do you still join on `produto`?

Comment: @RobertKock sorry, I mistake. This not work if I try only `produto_nota.lote like`

Comment: I know very little about MySql but it seems it has to do with binary strings which are compared case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have that row on the JOIN.

Because the where condition is working properly if the row is present.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f8ae8e/1)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
where nota_lote like '%1b%' or produco_descricao like '%1b%' limit 20
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| nota_id | produco_descricao | nota_lote |
|---------|-------------------|-----------|
|       1 |              TEST |      1B60 |
```

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` comparison is case-sensitive.
Try this:

```
where UPPER(produto_nota.lote) like '%1B%' or UPPER(produto.descricao) like '%1B%'
```

or

```
where LOWER(produto_nota.lote) like '%1b%' or LOWER(produto.descricao) like '%1b%'
```

Comment: Hi. If I try `where produto_nota.lote like '%1b%'` this works correctly. So, is not case-sensitive comparison

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm used to Oracle. Forget my answer.